# Elm: JSON decoder, convert String to Bool

Tags: elm

I'm receiving a JSON that looks like this:

```
{ name: "NAME1", value: "true" }
```

I would like to create a json decoder that would create a record like this:

```
{ name: "NAME1", value: True }
```

I'm trying to make a decoder that transforms "true" into True. I did this so far:

```
userProperties : Json.Decode.Decoder Props
userProperties =
  Json.Decode.object2 (,)
    ("name" := Json.Decode.string)
    ("value" := Json.Decode.string)
      `andThen` \val ->
        let
          newVal = -- Do something here?
        in
          Json.Decode.succeed <| newVal
```

Comment: You've got `val` which should be `"true"` in your example, so writing the assignment to `newVal` should be fairly trivial, depending on exactly what semantics you want - potentially just an `if` expression. What's the problem you're having with figuring it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few problems in your example so let's step through each of them.

You haven't shown the definition of `Props` so I'm assuming, based on your example, that it is this:

```elm
type alias Props = { name : String, value : Bool }
```

You are passing `(,)` as the first argument to `object2` which indicates that you will be returning a Decoder of type tuple. That should probably be:

```elm
Json.Decode.object2 Props
```

Now, the way you are using `andThen` won't compile because of its order of precedence. If you were to parenthesize the whole thing, it would look like this:

```elm
userProperties =
  (Json.Decode.object2 Props
    ("name" := Json.Decode.string)
    ("value" := Json.Decode.string))
      `andThen` \val ->
        let
          newVal = -- Do something here?
        in
          Json.Decode.succeed <| newVal
```

That isn't going to be correct since the thing you want to `andThen` is the string `"true"` in the `"value"` field. To do that, I would recommend creating a decoder which provides that boolean decoder:

```elm
stringBoolDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Bool
stringBoolDecoder =
  string `andThen` \val ->
    case val of
      "true" -> succeed True
      "false" -> succeed False
      _ -> fail <| "Expecting \"true\" or \"false\" but found " ++ val
```

I'm only guessing at the handling of `"false"` and the catch-all underscore. Change their implementation as suits your business case.

When building complex decoders, it is often best to break up decoder definitions into the smallest chunk possible like in the above.

Lastly, we can now redefine your `userProperties` decoder to use the `stringBoolDecoder` in the appropriate place:

```elm
userProperties : Json.Decode.Decoder Props
userProperties =
  Json.Decode.object2 Props
    ("name" := Json.Decode.string)
    ("value" := stringBoolDecoder)
```

Comment: Great answer! I'm slowly connecting the dots with the FP approach.