# Elm: decoding floats encoded as strings in JSON

Tags: json, functional-programming, elm

I'm looking to decode floats in JSON that are in quotes.

```
import Html exposing (text)    
import Json.Decode as Decode

type alias MonthlyUptime = {
  percentage: Maybe Float
}

decodeMonthlyUptime =
  Decode.map MonthlyUptime
    (Decode.field "percentage" (Decode.maybe Decode.float))        

json = "{ \"percentage\": \"100.0\" }"   
decoded = Decode.decodeString decodeMonthlyUptime json  

main = text (toString decoded)
```

(Execute [here](http://elm-lang.org/try))

This outputs `Ok { percentage = Nothing }`.

I've been fairly confused by the documentation surrounding custom decoders, and it looks like some of it is out of date (for instance, references to `Decode.customDecoder`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Elm 0.19.1**

```
Decode.field "percentage" Decode.string
    |> Decode.map (String.toFloat >> MonthlyUptime)
```

---

**Original answer**

Instead of the `andThen` I would suggest using a `map`:

```
Decode.field "percentage" 
    (Decode.map 
       (String.toFloat >> Result.toMaybe >> MonthlyUptime)
       Decode.string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I figured it out with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157902/elm-json-decoder-convert-string-to-bool?rq=1)

```
import Html exposing (text)

import Json.Decode as Decode

json = "{ \"percentage\": \"100.0\" }"

type alias MonthlyUptime = {
  percentage: Maybe Float
}

decodeMonthlyUptime =
  Decode.map MonthlyUptime
    (Decode.field "percentage" (Decode.maybe stringFloatDecoder))

stringFloatDecoder : Decode.Decoder Float
stringFloatDecoder =
  (Decode.string)
  |> Decode.andThen (\val ->
    case String.toFloat val of
      Ok f -> Decode.succeed f
      Err e -> Decode.fail e)

decoded = Decode.decodeString decodeMonthlyUptime json


main = text (toString decoded)
```